# Can I run existing MS Windows in parallel to OSX?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, virtualbox, boot-camp

I've installed Windows 7 on the separation partition of my HDD of Macbook (with Bootcamp). Is there any way to run it without rebooting (i.e. as separate application)? Something like Oracle VM Virtualbox runs?

I don't want to create separate VMPlayer / Virtualbox image with Windows since it will be different from what I have installed with Bootcamp.

Comment: This isn't a real answer, so I'll leave a comment. If you google "VirtualBox Bootcamp," you'll find plenty of guides on how to do this. VMware Fusion and Parallels Desktop also support this.

Comment: @PatrickS., interesting - VMWare Fusion FAQ (https://www.vmware.com/support/fusion/faq/prod_info.html) says that it `can easily create a Windows virtual machine based on your Boot Camp Windows installation`, i.e. I will have two copies of Windows instead of one (what I am looking for).

Comment: That's not what happens. It creates a VM with your boot camp partition as the hard drive. So you still only have one Windows. You can then either load this Bootcamp VM while Mac OS is running, or you can reboot into Bootcamp to run Windows only.

Comment: Thanks, @PatrickS. I've checked it yesterday - you are right.